# Filtering a JSON nested array based on user selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, filtering

I have a little problem using jQuery and sorting a JSON array.

What I'm tring to do is to filter a geoJSON array depending on the hour selected by user.
The user can select a hours range using a jQuery slider.

```
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val("h" + ui.values[0]+":00" + 
                             "h" + ui.values[1]+":00");
            minSel =ui.values[0];
            maxSel =ui.values[1];

            //HERE SHOULD BE PLACED THE FILTER FUNCTION
            filterArray(minSel,maxSel);
        }
    });
```

How can can I return only the array values between the hour selection ordered by their `visitedTimes`?

Here below there's a sample of the array.

Can anyone help me?

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [   
 {   "type": "Feature",
    "id": "...",
    "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [...]},
    "properties": {    "venueName": "Its name",

                       "visitedTimes": "1", 
                       "day": "07",
                       "month": "09",
                       "hour": "00",
                       "min": "50",
                       "sec": "58"
    }
},
{   "type": "Feature",
    "id": "4bd34eca462cb7133d1dde07",
    "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [...]},
    "properties": { "venueName": "Old Wild West",
                       "visitedTimes": "4", 
                       "day": "07",
                       "month": "09",
                       "hour": "00",
                       "min": "51",
                       "sec": "21"
    }
},
{   "type": "Feature",
    "id": "...",
    "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [...]},
    "properties": { "venueName": "Past & future",
                       "day": "07",
                       "month": "09",
                       "hour": "00",
                       "min": "51",
                       "sec": "23"
    }
}
]}
```

Comment: I assume you are going to parse the JSON into a JavaScript object, so your problem is actually not JSON related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the jQuery.grep(array, function(elementOfArray, indexInArray) ) function to filter the array.

Then use the javascript sort function with a custom comparator function to sort by visitedTimes.